# Отображение новых цен без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, websocket

Для сайта с аукционом необходимо изменять цену на странице в лайфтайме, те без перезагрузки страницы. Натолкните на мысль, в какую сторону копать и с помощью какой технологии можно это реализовать?

Использую фреймворк Yii2

Comment: ну у вас же даже тег стоит нужный, websocket. В голове не укладывается, как можно угадать все буквы, но не угадать слово. Знать все нужные для поиска в гугле слова, но сидеть, голову ломать, "как же отправить новую цену на фронт?"

Comment: @Ипатьев на одном форуме прочел такую вещь "Зачем тащить сюда фуру, если можно обойтись самокатом". Исходя из этого я задал здесь вопрос, возможно кто-то подскажет более простую идею

Comment: Ну-ну. Тогда ждите подсказок, чо.

Comment: @Ипатьев Я не жду, я изучаю. Это не первостепенная задача. К тому времени, возможно кто-то и поделится своими мыслями

Comment: @Ипатьев Вместо того чтобы придираться предложи свою идею, как бы ты это реализовал. И я не говорю про готовое решение на блюде, я про мысли.

Comment: Все мысли я уже изложил в первом комментарии

Comment: @Ипатьев Спасибо